# Random walk with stopping time

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

$T_n=\Sigma_{j=1}^n Y_j$ is a symmetric simple random walk with $P(Y_j=1)=\frac{1}{2}, P(Y_j=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $T_0=0$. Define $M=\mbox{min}\{i:|T_i|=n\}$. We are require to find $\mathbb{E}(M)$ and $\mathbb{E}(M^2)$.

My thought: We can have $\mathbb{E}(Y_j)=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y_j) = 1$. Also $\mathbb{E}(T_n)=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(T_n)=n$. But how to calculate $\mathbb{E}(M)$ and $\mathbb{E}(M^2)$. Please help.

Comment: What is your background? What is the last thing that you learned before you were given this question to attempt? (Or decided to attempt it?) I'm asking because this could involve concepts beyond Markov chains, although I believe that this question can be done with first-step analysis.

Comment: I have calculated $E(T)$. By optional stopping theorem, it is n2. But can't understand how to find $E(T^2)$.

Comment: Oh, so you do know the optional stopping theorem! I couldn't have guessed that from the tags. You need a different martingale for $T^2$ : For finding $E[T]$, I'm sure you'd have used the martingale $S_n^2-n$ so that $E[S_T^2] = E[T]$. For $T^2$, you need to do something a little more wild, which is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75969/expectation-of-ts-t-where-t-is-the-absorption-time-at-a-a-of-a-simple?noredirect=1&lq=1). I wanted to ask for your background because I wanted to make sure you could understand what is written here.

Comment: Apply the optimal stopping theorem to the exponential martingale $$ X_n = \frac{e^{\lambda T_n}}{(\cosh \lambda)^n}, \qquad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, $$ to show that $$ \mathbb{E}[(\operatorname{sech} \lambda)^M] = \operatorname{sech}(n\lambda). $$ Then by expanding both sides in $\lambda$ you can in principle determine any moments of $M$. For instance, we get $$ \mathbf{E}[M] = n^2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \mathbf{E}[M^2] = \frac{n^2 (5 n^2 - 2)}{3}. $$